# What is the Pythonic way to create informative comments in Python 2.x?

Tags: python, comments

For further clarification, C# has the '///' directive which invokes the super-secret-styled Comments which allow you to have nice comments built into intellisense. Java has the '@' directive that allows you to have nice comments as well.

Does Python have something like this? I hope this question is clear enough, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python a docstring can be viewed via commands.

```
class myClass:
    """
      This is some documentation for the class.
      method1()
      method2()
    """
    def method1(p1):
        ....
        ...
        ...
    def method2():
        ...
        ...

v = myClass
```

you can then view the docstring by using either

```
v.__doc__
```

or

```
help(myClass)
```

Comment: it's not a comment, it's a doc string. Comments in Python start with a `#` sign.

Comment: @SilentGhost Thanks for the correction, python hasn't gotten much of my time and attention over the years, so I miss a lot of the finer details.

Answer (score 7):

They are called docstrings in Python. [See the documentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

A nice feature are the code samples ([explained here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/documenting/markup.html#showing-code-examples)). They allow to put code in the documentation:

```
>>> 1 + 1
2
>>>
```

While this doesn't look like much, there is a tool which can scan the docstrings for such patterns and *execute this code as unit tests*. This makes sure that Python documenation doesn't go out of date (unlike in other languages).

Comment: For those who are interested, the module to use the docstring for unittests is called doctest.

Answer (score 2):

Python does not have "the" tool for generating documentation. One of the available tools I can recommend is [epydoc](http://epydoc.sf.net). It supports directives like @type, @param, @rtype, @returns and @raises. The website also has a few examples.

Answer (score 2):

The convention is well documented in [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

To summarize, add triple-quoted strings as the first statement in any class or function.

There's also some history that's worth a read if you have time in [PEP 256](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0256/).

Answer (score 0):

as other people has pointed out in Python the resource you are looking for is called doc string.
other people has suggested read the documentation, alibeit I suggest watch this link

[Sphinx Project](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/), this is an system like Sand Castle that help you building and elaborate documentation, this documentation can be build from doc string but is not mandatory.

hope this helps